# Changed folder contents not updating in Finder (OS X 10.8)

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion

I've been having this problem for a number of days now.  When I update the contents of a folder using terminal commands, by decompressing archives, or by using "Save As", the affected folder often fails to reflect these changes.  Sometimes it takes quite a while for any files to be shown, even if the total size of the folder is fairly small (< 10 MB).

I'm running an '09 MacBook Pro 13", so it isn't the newest system, but it certainly has enough oomph to display a list of files in a folder.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: You may be running into indexing delays. Spotlight indexes pretty much every folder on your drive, and visibility of the data is affected by how quickly this happens. How many files are we talking about? Perhaps your Spotlight database needs rebuilding. Try removing the .DS_Store file from the folder as well.

Comment: Do you use Dropbox perhaps?

Comment: @slhck Found this on a Google search, and yes I do use Dropbox. Is this a known issue?